# Ofstream creates but wont write to file

Tags: c++, file, logging, ofstream

I have wrote some code that does a basic fizzbuzz program to test my logging class, for some reason the data is dumped to the console fine and the file is created fine however the log file is empty whenever I open it.

My main is here:

```
int main()
{
    logger* loggerObj = logger::createLogger("log.txt");

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        loggerObj->createLogEvent(i);

        if (i == 15)
        {
           loggerObj->writeLog();
        }
}
```

and this is my class:

```
int logger::m_instanceCount = 0;
logger* logger::loggerObj = new logger;
string logger::m_fileName = "log.txt";

logger::logger()
{
}

logger::~logger()
{
}

logger* logger::createLogger(string fileName)
{
    if (m_instanceCount == 0)
    {
        loggerObj = new logger;
        m_fileName = fileName;

        return loggerObj;
    }
    else
    {
        return loggerObj;
    }
}

bool logger::addLogToQueue(logEvent event)
{
    if (m_queueID == 15)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        queue[m_queueID] = event;
        m_queueID++;
        return true;
    }
}

void logger::logQueue()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= m_queueID; i++)
    {
        int level = getEventLevel(i);
        string message = getEventMessage(i);

        writeLog();
    }
}

int logger::getEventLevel(int logID)
{
    return queue[logID].logLevel;
}

string logger::getEventMessage(int logID)
{
    return queue[logID].logMessage;
}

void logger::writeLog()
{
    ofstream log(m_fileName, ios::out);
    log.open(m_fileName, ios::out);
    log.flush();
    string prefix;
    int level;
    string message;
    int queueSize = m_queueID;

    for (int i = 0; i <= queueSize - 1; i++)
    {
        level = queue[i].logLevel;
        message = queue[i].logMessage;

        switch (level)
        {
        case 1:
            prefix = "[Fizz] ";
            break;
        case 2:
            prefix = "[Buzz] ";
            break;
        case 3:
            prefix = "[FizzBuzz] ";
            break;
        default:
            prefix = "[Number] ";
            break;
        }

        string fullMessage = prefix.append(message);
        cout << fullMessage << endl;
        log << fullMessage << endl;

        m_queueID--;
    }

    log.close();
}

void logger::createLogEvent(int number)
{
    logEvent event;
    if (number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 == 0)
    {
        event.logLevel = 3;
        event.logMessage = to_string(number);
    }
    else if (number % 3 == 0)
    {
        event.logLevel = 1;
        event.logMessage = to_string(number);
    }
    else if (number % 5 == 0)
    {
        event.logLevel = 2;
        event.logMessage = to_string(number);
    }
    else
    {
        event.logMessage = to_string(number);
    }

    addLogToQueue(event);
}
```

this is my class header:

```
#ifndef LOGGER_INCLUDED
#define LOGGER_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class logger
{
public:
    ~logger();
    struct logEvent;
    static logger* createLogger(string);
    bool addLogToQueue(logEvent);
    void logQueue();
    void createLogEvent(int);
    int getEventLevel(int);
    string getEventMessage(int);
    void writeLog();
private:
    logger();
    struct logEvent
    {
        string logMessage;
        int logLevel;
    };
    static int m_instanceCount;
    static logger* loggerObj;
    static string m_fileName;
    logEvent queue[15];
    int m_queueID = 0;
};

#endif
```

This is my first time trying logging so if its a simple mistake please forgive me. Thanks in advance. Also this is not designed to be the best or most efficient, its merely training hence the use of singletons and queues that aren't really needed, just trying some stuff out

Comment: I don't know how you approached writing this code, but you're supposed to do incremental changes and testing.   Not being able to write to a file should have been caught early in the process of writing such a class.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie please read the whole thing, i outlined at the bottom this was merely a training exercise. I understand the process of writing software and usually i do this in a TDD fashion with gmock however i was just trying a few things out and then was deleting it so no need to TDD it all.

Comment: You open the file for reading twice. `ofstream log(m_fileName, ios::out);  log.open(m_fileName, ios::out);`

Comment: @sleeptightpupper i commented out the 'log.open(m_fileName, ios::out);' line and it works now. I didnt know the creation of 'log' opened it on its own. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ofstream log(m_fileName, ios::out);
log.open(m_fileName, ios::out);
```

The constructor opens the file.

Immediately afterwards, the second line attempts to `open()` the file again. That's an error. The file stream's `std::failbit` is set, and all subsequent write operations fail.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed now, i wasnt aware it was being opened twice.

Comment: Needs more detail to be useful as an answer. Currently this is a comment posing as an answer.